# Assessing the closest future date to today from 4 columns with dates in SQL

Tags: date, sql-server-2008

I have a table which features 4 columns of dates.  I need to calculate in column 5 the date which is the closest future date to today and display this within the same row e.g. is the 20th anniv closer that the 85th birthday or is theh 10th anniv closer than the 85th birthday.  NB the 85th birthday will alway be the maximum date. Column 6 needs to then display the appriopriate column heading

Really appreciate any help that any one can offer.

```
Column names / sample values

strt date     - 01/01/2010  
85th birthday - 11/12/2047   
10th anniv    - 01/01/2020  
20th anniv    - 01/01/2030  
next date     - 01/01/2030  
anniv_type    - 20th anniv
```

Comment: your description is rather confusing. You mention `4 columns of dates`, `need to calculate in column 5 the date` and `Column 6`. Can you please indicate what is the name of all those columns ? With reference to the sample data that you have shown

Comment: sorry first time posting here.  The column names are on the left of the example above and sample outputs on the right, stuglled to post this correctly. I need to calculate the [next date] and [anniv_type] fields. Hope that clarifies?

Comment: for `next date` , you can use `dateadd(year, 20, strtdate )`

Comment: Sorry Squirrel, poor explanation on my part.  I've already got the calculation of {85th birthday], [10th anniv]. [20th anniv] already using these code you've have suggested.  What I need to do is evaluate these 3 dates against getdate() and populate [next date] with the date the date closest to getdate() in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The following query uses `CROSS APPLY` to `UNPIVOT` the 4 date columns and then get the one closest to current date. `TOP 1` is to get only one row ie the nearest date

```
select  *
from    yourtable t
        cross apply
        (
            select  top 1 *
            from    
            (
                values  ([strt date], 'strt date'),
                        ([85th birthday], '85th birthday'),
                        ([10th anniv], '10th anniv'),
                        ([20th anniv], '20th anniv')
            ) d ([next date], [anniv_type])
            where   [next date] > getdate()
            order by datediff(day, getdate(), [next date])
        ) n
```